# how to get all the fields of an selected object(standard and custom) in an org using lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components

i had populate all the object names in the org by using "iteration"in lightning component then i got all object names shown below    then my requirement is whenever i onclick any objectname i need to display all fields of that object               [image]

Answer (score 0):

You can get the fields name from the Object name using describe call:

```
String SobjectApiName = 'Account';
Map<String, Schema.SObjectType> schemaMap = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> fieldMap = schemaMap.get(SobjectApiName).getDescribe().fields.getMap();
for(String fieldName : fieldMap.keyset() )
    {
        system.debug('fieldName -->'+fieldName); // This will give you the api name of the field name.
    }
```